# Rotate touchpad in-line with screen

Tags: touchpad, rotate

I have a samsung NC10 netbook with the intel graphics media accelerator for mobile installed, which gives me hotkeys for rotating the screen. Is is possible to also "rotate" the touchpad. So that, for example is I rotate my screen 90 degrees anti-clockwise so that the keyboard is now to the left of the screen, left on the mouse becomes up, so that my touchpad work in sync with the screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](http://www.math.uaa.alaska.edu/~afkjm/techteach/?q=node/70) seems
to be what you are looking for, it works fine on Windows 7 but the screen stays rotated once the program is closed.

Comment: +1 since there's situations i'd find this very useful in ;p

Comment: Downvoted because it relies on a link for 100% of useful information. The link is now dead, which is predictable.